# How to SSH interactive Session

Tags: ruby, ssh

Good day everyone

I need to execute command on linux machine this command is interactive
command.
Interactive command means require input like [yes , no] or password
twice

my real case is.
I create a script execute commands and get the outputs successfully.
but some servers has Loging password expired so I need to interact with
server to send the current password + the new password(twice)

```
ssh userName@10.0.0.243
userName@10.0.0.243's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)
Last login: Sun Aug  7 13:15:40 2011 from 10.0.0.28
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user userName.
Changing password for userName
(current) UNIX password:
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```

Notes::

- I'm using Ruby 1.9.2
- I've no problem in executing command in normal case
- please, I have to avoid workarounds like (echo "pass" | ssh -S) to make me pass any other interactive situations.
- I'm using 'net/ssh' libs
- The Script is Attached http://king-sabri.net/files/LinuxHWScanner.rb
- I tried "net/ssh/telnet" and it doesn't help
- Some advises tell useing 'rake/remote_task' is the solution but I can't understand how it works in my case

if you need more simplicity, here a simple code if you make it works I thing it'll solve my previous issue

```
  require 'net/ssh'

  host = "10.0.0.106"
  port = 22     # SSH port
  user = 'root'     # username
  pass = "123123"   # password

Net::SSH.start( host,user,:password => pass, :port=> port , :verbose => :error ) do |session|

 puts session.exec!("passwd root")
end
```

Comment: You will probably need to use the [`request_pty()` function](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Channel.html#M000055) to run the `passwd(1)` program.

Comment: @sarnold can you advise about request_pty() in my case ?

Comment: I was wrong: from reading the Shadow Password Suite source code, I see that `gpasswd(1)`, `login(1)`, `su(1)`, and `sulogin(8)` all require to be run from a terminal. But not `passwd(1)`. Go figure.

Comment: But you were right in the sense that if it's automatically invoked `passwd` on login, then the only way to get the greeting text asking you to change the pass is to `request_pty`. afaik..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Net::SSH.start('10.0.0.6', 'not_root', :password => "test") do |ssh|
   ssh.open_channel do |channel|
      channel.on_request "exit-status" do |channel, data|
        $exit_status = data.read_long
      end
      channel.exec("passwd") do |channel, success|
        if success
          channel.on_data do |channel, data|
            # Don't really need this callback actually
            puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
          end
          # You don't need this line if you're root
          channel.send_data("oldpass\n")
          channel.send_data("newpass\n")
          channel.send_data("newpass\n")
        else
           puts "FAILED"
        end
      end
      channel.wait
      puts "SUCCESS" if $exit_status == 0
   end
end
```

This one is dirty, but working for both upon premature on-expiration prompt and upon `passwd` issuing:

```
Net::SSH.start('localhost', 'not_root', :password => "test") do |ssh|
  ssh.open_channel do |channel|
     channel.on_request "exit-status" do |channel, data|
        $exit_status = data.read_long
     end
     channel.on_data do |channel, data|
        puts data.inspect
        if data.inspect.include? "current"
                channel.send_data("oldpass\n");
        elsif data.inspect.include? "new"
                channel.send_data("newpass\n");
        end
     end
     channel.request_pty
     # This will just safely fail if we have already a password prompt on
     channel.exec("passwd");
     channel.wait
     # Will reflect a valid status in both cases
     puts $exit_status
  end
end
```

Comment: No bro. it's doesn't works

I test it , no error no session hanging , but not result (password is not changed )

Comment: Just checked it's working. It wouldn't work when logged in as root user, because root has privileges to set a new password for **anyone** without confirming an old one.

Comment: Oh ,, here a some good news 
it's working now but after I remove
channel.send_data("oldpass\n")
but I still face a problem when password is expired notice if password is expired I cant execute "password" command. 
the terminal prmpt me to enter the current and the new password. put you help me for good forward step. can you help to solve this last issue of password expiration ? please

Comment: Dear </br>
it's hang after "Retype new password"</br>
</br><code>ruby chgpass-dev.rb 
"WARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\n"
"Changing password for user hi.\r\n"
"Changing password for hi.\r\n(current) UNIX password: "
"\r\n"
"New password: "
"\r\nRetype new password: "`</code>

Comment: `New` and `new` in the 2nd and 3rd prompt are of different case (this thing varies between distros). Just change the condition(s) in on_data callback.

Comment: you right , but the 1st "New" is capitalized & 2nd is downcast.

Comment: Here We Are ,,, the Issue has been solved.. Please take a look 
<blink>
        if data.inspect.include? "current"
                channel.send_data("CurrentPass\n");
        elsif data.inspect.include? "New"
                channel.send_data("NewPass\n");
 elsif data.inspect.include? "new"
                channel.send_data("NewPass\n");
</blink>

Comment: @forker - I have a small issue with ssh connection state. Please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799593/unix-commands-work-on-server-but-not-in-ruby-ssh-session thanks.