# How to skip incorrect ssh passwords

Tags: ruby, ssh

I have a script that logs into 1000+ wireless units and audits and them. Some of their passwords have been changed. I would like to skip these units without specifically telling ruby which ips to skip. The script is multithreaded and gets hung up because when ruby sshes into a unit and uses the wrong password it will ask for the password and the whole script comes to a halt.

*How to skip or rescue wrong password attempts for ruby net/ssh

```
Net::SSH.start('ip','user',password: 'pass', paranoid: false) do |ssh|

end
```

with the incorrect password will prompt you like so

```
admin@192.168.1.1's password:
```

Comment: Your question is too broad as it would take a small book to explain the possible solutions. Perhaps if you showed us some code where the problem occurs we could help you better.

Comment: Edited in simple example code

Comment: When you SSH into a device you can use channels to communicate over, and send and read responses from the device. You should be looking for a response that ends with "password:", then you can close the connection or send the appropriate password. The documentation is complex but it does show how to get it working.

Comment: @theTinMan: Please post your comment as a solution, ideally with a link to *“The documentation”* that you refer to. That way the OP can accept it and avoid a hung question. Thanks.

Comment: @theTinMan I don't think that will work because in order for the channel to be established, the authentication must be passed. Let me know if i'm wrong

Comment: @Borodin, unfortunately, the Net::SSH documentation needed to do what he wants is spread out. There is no specific example to point to, it takes a lot of reading. And, a solution would require one HUGE answer, well beyond a concise answer.

Comment: @theTinMan: Fair enough, but please post *something* as I doubt there will be a better answer

Comment: @Schylar, the fact that you're seeing a message at all shows that SSH has made a connection and a channel is open. Correct, you haven't authenticated, but that's part of the flow of the conversation of client <--> server. It's complicated and takes a lot of digging around but there are examples out there that will help.

Comment: There's really nothing to post unless I have something more useful than "You gotta do more research." It's just a complicated protocol and has always been that way. It's a nightmare compared to working with HTTP.

Comment: I would recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7942189/128421 as it shows the use of channels and processing passwords. Also, perhaps setting the session timeouts to short intervals would help so the session won't hang. Otherwise we use a backing database of our networking devices (we have thousands of them) and that database is our knowledge repository of what devices need to be touched, and how to touch them. It's better to know what's safe to do to a device than to try to do it by experimenting. A lot of bad can happen in a split second if code does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module Net::SSH::PromptMethods::Clear
    def prompt(prompt,echo = false)
        raise Error, "Details"
      # $stdout.print(prompt)
      # $stdout.flush
      # $stdin.gets.chomp
    end
end
```

Ended up using something similar to this

Answer (score 3):

In latest net-ssh (2.10.0.beta1), the new option **:non_interactive** was added to ignore the password prompt. Here are [the details](https://github.com/mfazekas/net-ssh/commit/2ce69f5a7895abaaec1168b9394b5eafa616e74c).

It works for me. For your case it should be

```
Net::SSH.start('ip','user',password: 'pass', paranoid: false, :non_interactive=>true) do |ssh|

end
```

Comment: Seems to work, but paranoid is now called verify_host_key.

Answer (score 2):

options = {
        password: password,
        number_of_password_prompts: 0,
        timeout: SSH_TIMEOUT
    }

try to use 'number_of_password_prompts: 0,', It may be perfect